# Getting 'Google_Service_Exception' using with reseller api scope

Tags: google-api, google-reseller-api

Getting 'Google_Service_Exception' using the reseller API scope:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message": "Insufficient Permission" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission" } } ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\customerportal\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\customerportal\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\customerportal\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(181): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\customerportal\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\customerportal\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Goog in C:\xampp\htdocs\customerportal\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 118

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Reseller API: Authorizing](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/authorizing) guide on how to authorize your requests. 
Follow the steps indicated and don't forget the scope, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.order`.